# ¿Como muestro el usuario logueado?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, login

es que tengo un form que manda los datos de usuario y contraseña a value.php que es donde está todo el proceso de verificación del login, y quiero que el usuario que se loguee salga en index.php

Codigo de value.php:

```
<?php

// 1. Conexion con el servidor y la base de datos
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tips');
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "ERROR al conectar con la DB.";
    exit;

}


// 2. isset() del boton login
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    // 3. Variables $_POST[]
    $u = $_POST['usuario'];
    $c = ($_POST['clave']); // La función MD5() estará encriptando lo ingresado para comparar con lo guardado

    if($u == "" || $_POST['clave'] == null){ // Validamos que ningún campo quede vacío
        echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave vacios!!');</script>"; // Se utiliza Javascript dentro de PHP
    }else{
        // 4. Cadena de SQL
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usunombre = '$u' AND usuclave = '$c'";

        // 5. Ejecuto cadena query()
        if(!$consulta = $conexion->query($sql)){
            echo "ERROR: no se pudo ejecutar la consulta!";
        }else{

            // 6. Cuento registros obtenidos del select. 
            // Como el nombre de usuario en la clave primaria no debería de haber mas de un registro con el mismo nombre.
            $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

            // 7. Comparo cantidad de registros encontrados
            if($filas == 0){
                echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave incorrectos!!');</script>";
            }else{
                header('location:admin.php'); // Si está todo correcto redirigimos a otra página
            }

        }
    }
}


?>
```

necesito que en el nombre de usuario que se loguee aparezca en esta pag donde dice BIENVENIDO ... Digamos Bienvenido Pepito y pepito es el que se logueo ayuda por favor

Codigo de index.php:

```
<?php include_once('value.php') ?>
<div class="views-admin">


    <div id="general">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div><h2 style="color: black;" align="center">BIENVENID@ </h2></div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div id="contpanel">
            <ul align="center">
                <li><img src="#">
                    <a href="editequipo">Editar equipo</a></li>

                <li><img src="#">
                    <a href="#">Agregar Articulo (en mantenimiento)</a></li>

                <li><img src="#">
                    <a href="#">Editar Articulo (en mantenimiento)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <p align="center" style="color:black;">lorem</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Ayuda por favor sin esto no puedo terminar el resto de mi página

Comment: te recomiendo no usar MD5, y en vez de eso usar `password_hash` y `password_verify`, para que busques de ellos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Así como usas echo para imprimir strings puedes usarlo para variables. Por lo que veo en tu código que $u almacena el nombre de usuario puedes hacer esto:

```
<div id="general">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div><h2 style="color: black;" align="center">BIENVENID@ <?php echo $u;?> </h2></div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <div id="contpanel">
        <ul align="center">
            <li><img src="#">
                <a href="editequipo">Editar equipo</a></li>

            <li><img src="#">
                <a href="#">Agregar Articulo (en mantenimiento)</a></li>

            <li><img src="#">
                <a href="#">Editar Articulo (en mantenimiento)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <p align="center" style="color:black;">lorem</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque desconozco el contexto donde quieres usar esto, y probablemente por ello esto no sea la solución más apropiada, debería solventar tu problema.

Utilizando el array $_SESSION puedes acceder a variables con ámbito en otros archivos .php

Sin embargo, para que esto funcione, debes iniciar una sesión en PHP en todos los archivos donde quieras pasar datos de variables, y esto debe ser lo primero que hagas en un archivo .php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

En value.php puedes asignar el valor de $u a un índice del array $_SESSION, como por ejemplo; `$u = $_SESSION["NombreDeUsuario"]`

Después, en index.php puedes hacer un echo o print de `$_SESSION["NombreDeUsuario"]`

Hay que tener en cuenta que se debe tener algo de cautela al manejar sesiones en PHP. Sería recomendable que mirases tambíen `session_unset()` y `session_destroy()`